# Google Maps <div> kills other page elements

Tags: html, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I've three elements: two tables and a div which is the canvas for gMaps. when this line

```
<div id="map-canvas"/>
```

is present, gMaps is displayed correctly, but my other elements aren't visible. Neither do they appear when inspecting element in FireFox. When the line is not present, gMaps goes away of course, and my other elements display correctly. What can the reasons be? My entire code is appended because it is relatively short.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css"> /*gMaps style*/
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        #map-canvas { height: 50%; position: fixed; top: 50%;}
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript">//jQuery for color picker</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">//gMap API</script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js">//tablesorter</script>
</script>




    <script type="text/javascript">     //gMap API
        function initialize() {

            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: center,
            zoom: 2,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>






<script>//colorpicker
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#palette td').click(function(){
            color = $(this).css('background-color');    
            $('body').css('background-color' , color);
        });

    });

</script>

<script>//tablesorter

    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
    ); 

</script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>

    <table id="palette">
        <tr>
            //table elements
        </tr>
    </table>


        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                //table head
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
            //table body
            </tbody> 
        </table> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It seems that map-canvas style `top: 50%;` influence this behaviour. If you comment it out you will get a map in upper part and tables after the map.

Comment: Yes. You map is 50% of height and you set top to 50% which means 50% from the top. And there is no place for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div's *shouldn't* be self-closing...

Try replacing `<div id="map-canvas"/>` with `<div id="map-canvas"></div>`

Comment: I did this and also moved the map below the other elements. Whole page now displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the map is overlaying the other elements (can you see them if you use the dev console) as mentioned in comments above.

Either position the divs accordingly underneath the map, remove the fixed positioning entirely or add z-indexes if overlap was your intention.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) about CSS top property:

*The top CSS property specifies part of the position of positioned elements. It has no effect on non-positioned elements.*

*For absolutely positioned elements (those with position: absolute or position: fixed), it specifies the distance between the top margin edge of the element and the top edge of its containing block.*

With `top: 50%;` you spent whole place for the map. Even 10% will not be good enough. If you do not need some special arrangement you can left it out.

And `<div>` element has to be properly closed:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```